# Which encodings are preferable to use Z3 to solve a partial order theory?

Tags: z3, smt, partial-ordering

I'm considering diverse ways of encoding a partial order relation to feed it Z3.

The problem is already constrained in various ways and uses QF_ logic variants (LIA or LRA mostly).

I have additional constraints I could express that refine the solution with a partial order, in the form of, if variable `ei>0 => a0 precedes ai`, where `ei` is a variable of my problem that exists and `ai` variables are new, and represent "precedes" partial order constraints.

So this partial order will limit the solutions obtained in terms of ei in diverse ways.

A solution could be to use uninterpreted functions like this example :
https://rise4fun.com/Z3/fZQc

```
; Coding a partial order precedes relation with UF
(declare-sort A)
(declare-fun pre (A A) Bool)
; non reflexive
(assert (forall ((x A)) (not (pre x x))))
; transitive
(assert (forall ((x A) (y A) (z A))
          (=> (and (pre x y) (pre y z)) 
              (pre x z)))) 
; anti symetric
(assert (forall ((x A) (y A))
          (=> (pre x y)  
              (not (pre y x)))))
; an UNSAT example
(declare-const a0 A)
(declare-const a1 A)
(declare-const a2 A)
(assert (pre a0 a1))
(assert (pre a1 a2))
(assert (pre a2 a0))
(check-sat)
```

This expresses exactly what I want, but this also introduces a new logic with quantifiers.

Another alternative is to plunge my elements into a concrete domain such as Real or Int :
https://rise4fun.com/Z3/U0Hp

```
; Coding a partial order precedes relation with Real
; an UNSAT example
(declare-const a0 Real)
(declare-const a1 Real)
(declare-const a2 Real)
(assert (< a0 a1))
(assert (< a1 a2))
(assert (< a2 a0))
(check-sat)
```

The code is simpler and does not use quantifiers, but it forces (maybe ?) the solver to over-think, since Real have many more properties than the abstract domain A in the first version.

So which encoding should usually be preferred to encode partial orders ?
Are there are additional parameters I should take into account or, maybe strategies I could configure to help solving this kind of problem ?

Comment: The issue with the reals is that they are totally ordered... if that's acceptable then it's certainly the easier way. I'll think a bit if there is a nice embedding into datatypes that's not too heavy on quantifiers.

Comment: well, since my constraints don't talk about equality, I do end up with a partial order even though I plunged into reals, two different variables could be equal; but yes this is additional constraints that force to combine e.g. two totally independent causal chains do end up "totally" ordered in reals, or at least the solver must think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid quantifiers if you can. SMT solver are just not good with them, especially in combinations of theories. If you can stick to `Int` or `Real`, great. If you can use bit-vectors, then that's even better since the logic will remain decidable even in the presence of non-linear functions.

If your model really requires quantifiers, I'd argue that an SMT solver is simply not a good match. In that case, look at semi-automated systems like Isabelle, Coq, HOL etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer which kind of fits my gut feeling, but in limited cases of interaction between the theories, should'nt the solver see it can use e.g. Tarjan on my abstract type A, rather than instantiate with reals ?

Comment: Impossible to tell without trying. The trouble is that the internals of the solver is more or less a black-box: Even small changes to the input can cause it to diverge and would be really hard to debug. If you can avoid it, stay away from quantifiers.

Comment: After experimenting with both solutions, for my use case, there is a huge performance gap (seconds or "unknown" down to millisecs) in favor of NOT using quantifiers, ie. we should prefer using the "plunge into Nat or Real" approach. So I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the built-in features for special relations.
At least they improve on the quadratic overhead of instantiating 
the partial order axioms. The built-in partial order relation is reflexive, 
so if you want an irreflexive version then define a macro that rules out
the reflexive case. (_ partial-order 0) is a relation that takes two arguments of the same sort and returns a Boolean. (_ partial-order 1) will be a different relation, thus you can index different partial orders using a parameter.

```
(declare-sort A)
(define-fun pre ((x A) (y A)) Bool (and (not (= x y)) ((_ partial-order 0) x y)))
; an UNSAT example
(declare-const a0 A)
(declare-const a1 A)
(declare-const a2 A)
(assert (pre a0 a1))
(assert (pre a1 a2))
(assert (pre a2 a0))
(check-sat)
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion I was not aware of that feature of Z3, but it certainly sems to be close to my use case. I'll try it and compare to the other options.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate a bit on how to have these functions available, e.g. Rise4Fun (and my experiments) both complain that : `invalid use of indexed identifier, unknown builtin function partial-order`. I searched the docs as well, but all I could find is this file that *you* authored apparently :D https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/86b98e3477e8f57ccbbcf7a1444ac8ffbf0fae73/src/ast/special_relations_decl_plugin.cpp

Comment: So based on this example, I could get a Partial Order to work, but this is the Python API, I could not find or make examples in SMT2 syntax work though. https://github.com/Z3Prover/doc/blob/master/programmingz3/code/special_relations.py There is also documentation of this "special relations" feature on this page : https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-special-relations but this is again Py API.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is related to "set-logic", any `set-logic` command apparently disables this "special_relations" feature, so I'm not sure how rise4fun is configured (it does not work even without a set-logic), but once I removed my `set-logic` from my code it ran without complaining on my local z3 instance.