# How can I optimize an smtlib query reasoning about partial orders?

Tags: z3, smt

I am working on trying to do type inference in Z3 for a compiler and the compiler generates a Z3 query over a fully defined partial order, and then attempts to find the maximal type for all the variables such that a fixed set of constraints is satisfied.

The query looks something like this:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Sort
(|SortInt| )
(|SortExp| )
(|SortKItem| )
(|SortKLabel| )
(|SortK| )
)))
(define-fun <=Sort ((s1 Sort) (s2 Sort)) Bool (or
  (and (= s1 |SortKItem|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortExp|) (= s2 |SortKItem|))
  (and (= s1 |SortExp|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortKItem|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortExp|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortKItem|) (= s2 |SortKItem|))
  (and (= s1 |SortKLabel|) (= s2 |SortKLabel|))
  (and (= s1 |SortExp|) (= s2 |SortExp|))
  (and (= s1 |SortK|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortInt|))
))
(define-fun <=SortSyntax ((s1 Sort) (s2 Sort)) Bool (or
  (and (= s1 |SortKItem|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortExp|) (= s2 |SortKItem|))
  (and (= s1 |SortExp|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortKItem|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortExp|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortKItem|) (= s2 |SortKItem|))
  (and (= s1 |SortKLabel|) (= s2 |SortKLabel|))
  (and (= s1 |SortExp|) (= s2 |SortExp|))
  (and (= s1 |SortK|) (= s2 |SortK|))
  (and (= s1 |SortInt|) (= s2 |SortInt|))
))
(push)
(declare-const |FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| Sort)
(declare-const |VarA| Sort)
(declare-const |VarB| Sort)
(declare-const |VarC| Sort)
(declare-datatypes() ((SolutionVariables (SolVars (|Sol_VarA| Sort) (|Sol_VarB| Sort) (|Sol_VarC| Sort) ))))
(declare-datatypes() ((Solution (Sol (vars SolutionVariables) (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| Sort) ))))
(define-fun theSolution () Solution (Sol (SolVars |VarA| |VarB| |VarC| ) |FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| ))
(define-fun lt ((s1 Solution) (s2 Solution)) Bool (and true (<=SortSyntax (|Sol_VarA| (vars s1)) (|Sol_VarA| (vars s2))) (<=SortSyntax (|Sol_VarB| (vars s1)) (|Sol_VarB| (vars s2))) (<=SortSyntax (|Sol_VarC| (vars s1)) (|Sol_VarC| (vars s2)))  (distinct (vars s1) (vars s2))))
(assert (and true (distinct (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| theSolution) |SortKLabel|) ))
(define-fun |constraint4_SortExp| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort (|Sol_VarA| (vars s)) |SortExp|) ))
(define-fun |constraint6_SortExp| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort (|Sol_VarB| (vars s)) |SortExp|) ))
(define-fun |constraint3_SortExp| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort |SortExp| |SortExp|) (|constraint4_SortExp| s) (|constraint6_SortExp| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint8_SortExp| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort (|Sol_VarC| (vars s)) |SortExp|) ))
(define-fun |constraint2_(Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite s)| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort |SortExp| (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| s)) (|constraint3_SortExp| s) (|constraint8_SortExp| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint12_SortInt| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort (|Sol_VarA| (vars s)) |SortInt|) ))
(define-fun |constraint14_SortInt| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort (|Sol_VarB| (vars s)) |SortInt|) ))
(define-fun |constraint11_SortInt| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort |SortInt| |SortInt|) (|constraint12_SortInt| s) (|constraint14_SortInt| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint16_SortInt| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort (|Sol_VarC| (vars s)) |SortInt|) ))
(define-fun |constraint10_(Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite s)| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort |SortInt| (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| s)) (|constraint11_SortInt| s) (|constraint16_SortInt| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint1_Sort#RuleBody| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (= (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| s) |SortK|) (|constraint2_(Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite s)| s) (|constraint10_(Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite s)| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint0_Sort#RuleContent| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (|constraint1_Sort#RuleBody| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint21_SortExp| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort |SortExp| |SortExp|) (|constraint6_SortExp| s) (|constraint8_SortExp| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint20_(Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite s)| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (<=Sort |SortExp| (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| s)) (|constraint4_SortExp| s) (|constraint21_SortExp| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint19_Sort#RuleBody| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (= (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| s) |SortK|) (|constraint20_(Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite s)| s) (|constraint10_(Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite s)| s) ))
(define-fun |constraint18_Sort#RuleContent| ((s Solution)) Bool (and true (|constraint19_Sort#RuleBody| s) ))
(define-fun amb0 ((s Solution)) Bool (or (|constraint0_Sort#RuleContent| s) (|constraint18_Sort#RuleContent| s) ))

(assert (amb0 theSolution))
(assert (not (exists ((s Solution)) (and (lt theSolution s) (amb0 s) (distinct (|Sol_FreshVarSort_6_8_6_36_#KRewrite| s) |SortKLabel|) ))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(assert (or false (distinct |VarA| |SortInt|) (distinct |VarB| |SortInt|) (distinct |VarC| |SortInt|) ))
(check-sat)
(pop)
```

This is a smaller query and runs fine. The problem is, when the number of sorts and variables and disjunctions in the constraints increases, z3 starts to take a significant amount of time to solve the constraints.

What I am wondering is, are there any specific tactics I could use or ways I could refactor the way the query is generated so queries of this type are faster on complex examples?

I can provide a larger query if it would be useful, but it's several hundred kilobytes.

Comment: Hard to say without digging deeper, but I'd hazard a guess that IDL (integer-difference logic) might work well for these sorts of problems. So, I'd try modeling your sorts with just plain integers and setting the logic to IDL. This way you can get rid of your `<=Sort`, and simply use the internal comparison, or subtract and assert `>=0`, for which there are better decision procedures and algorithms. See https://www.cs.upc.edu/~erodri/webpage/cps/theory/sat/SMT-DL/slides.pdf.

Comment: Wouldn't this convert the partial order into a total ordering? Note that for example, in the example above, it is neither true that `SortKLabel < SortInt`, `SortKLabel > SortInt`, nor `SortKLabel = SortInt`. It seems to me this would rather substantially deform the set of solutions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Another problem: it would appear that there is no `IDL` logic, only `QF_IDL`, but the query contains an existential quantifier.

Comment: Good point; it would make it a total-order. Perhaps you can recover partialness by doing a predicate and capturing what's not allowed. (That can defeat the purpose of it of course.)

Comment: Re `QF_IDL`: If `IDL` isn't supported, you might still set the logic to `ALL` (or not specify it), and then use tactics to get the benefits of IDL. Not sure how easy it would be to use though.

Comment: Also see this question, which seems quite relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59163248/which-encodings-are-preferable-to-use-z3-to-solve-a-partial-order-theory